# Datatables Jquery Dom Position

Tags: jquery, dom, datatables

I'm using http://datatables.net/ and I have a problem with the dom position.

The dom works if :

- I want to set 2 paginations `dom: "flptip"`
- I want to set all items at the top or bottom `dom: "tflip" / dom:
  "flipt"`

Btw the dom doesn't work if :

- I want to reverse the gobal search position with length position
  because I want the global search to the left and the length changing
  input control to the right. I can't doing `dom: "fltip"` there is
  no changes.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can try that mainly involve CSS for the specific `dom` element you want to move. You can include classes and ids when you specify the `dom` elements. From here, you can adjust where you want items aligned. Here's how you include

- < and > - div element
- <"class" and > - div with a class
- <"#id" and > - div with an ID

For example, you can do:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "dom": '<"#myTop"f>lt<"myBottom"i>p'
} );
```

Then CSS:

```
#myTop {
 text-align:left; /* whatever you need */
 }
.myBottom {
 text-align:right; /* whatever you need */
 }
```

[Documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom).

Comment: Wow awesome thanks a lot ! And do you know How I can add a `<div id="myDiv"></div>` to a table `<tr></tr>` ? cause I want to use the Jquery function slideToggle() to hide / show a row of my table.

Comment: Do you want to add a class to a specific row (harder) or to every row in a column (really easy)?

Comment: I want to add a div on the `tfoot` because I have filters inputs on each column in this `tfoot` and I want to hide and show this `tfoot` with `slideToggle()`

Comment: You should just be able to manually add like this in your HTML: `<tfoot id="something">`

Comment: It's impossible with datatable library. And if I want to use slideToggle() I must create a div around the tfoot or the tfoot tr

Comment: How do you define where the table goes in your HTML?

Comment: i'm using this https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: This solution doesn't work, see [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t80rmb93/) for confirmation.

Comment: It works in principle, but the CSS doesn't actually have any effect. I just put in `text-align` as a placeholder. Try it with `font-weight:bold;` instead and you'll see it working. By working...I mean selectively impacting the class or id. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/t80rmb93/1/